# How to access select boxes as array

Tags: php, html

I have four fields, out of them 3 is textboxes and 1 is dropdown. I am cloning them dynamically whenever user clicks on add more.

For textboxes i have given its name as array and its working fine (name="xyz[]").

Now the problem I am facing is with dropdown. I have tried same way to deal with it but its not working it seems. I can't access the values through PHP, it keeps giving me the values of the first select box only.

```
    <div class="cust-input">
          <select id="head_of_institute" name="head_of_institute[]">
                 <option>Select Management</option>
                 <option value="Principal">Principal</option>
                 <option value="Director">Director</option>
                 <option value="Other">Other</option>
          </select>
          <select id="head_of_institute" name="head_of_institute[]">
                 <option>Select Management</option>
                 <option value="Principal">Principal</option>
                 <option value="Director">Director</option>
                 <option value="Other">Other</option>
          </select>
    </div>
    <div class="cust-input">
         <input type="text" name="head_name[]">
         <input type="text" name="head_name[]">
    </div>
```

Can you please suggest how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: @Satpal please ignore.. it was there because of copy pasting the code :)

Comment: __What is not working__?

Comment: What is your actual problem is?

Comment: @Satpal dropdown is not working,, when i create two-three clone of it at that time

Comment: Just throwing in an idea (not tested and not sure if it works): have you tried `head_of_institute[][]` as name? Possibly it's not working as currently since the options are already an array.

Comment: How can you select multiple head of head_of_institute without multiple drop down?

Comment: @DarkAshelin not its not working

Comment: @Sadikhasan He is making multiple dropdowns, he's just having trouble assigning the `name` value. I assume he wants to access it in PHP through an array.

Comment: where is the code you're using to clone the elements?

Comment: Just print the value like print_r($_POST['head_of_institute']) and what you get?

Comment: @jasonscript I don't think that's very relevant. He just wants to know what name value he needs so he can access the select boxes through PHP as an array.

Comment: @user3164335 I proposed an edit to your question in the hopes of making it more clear what you are having trouble with. Please check if it is correct.

Comment: @DarkAshelin yes i want exactly what you said

Comment: @DarkAshelin have updated my question to clear what exact problem i am facing

Answer (score 1):

Your dropdown is not working only because, I'm sure that you are adding new dropdown with the same ID.

Yes, ID must be unique on a page. If you add same ID more than one then javascript will ignore another.

So, my suggestion is to add new dropdown with name="head_of_institute[]" and id="head_of_institute_1" here 1 can be a counter for next downdown it'll be head_of_institute_2.

:) enjoy!

Comment: you are creating dropbox with PHP or Javascript/Jquery?

Comment: @AlauddinAnsari The question has been updated to demonstrate more clearly what exactly the issue is. The issue is not with the js / query, just in html + php. The issue is not with creating the dropdown boxes, but assigning the `name` value correctly so it can be retrieved in PHP.

Comment: I've created an demo of the same code as you given in the question and checked it working fine. My output in PHP is:

    Array
    (
        [head_of_institute] => Array
            (
                [0] => Director
                [1] => Principal
            )

        [head_name] => Array
            (
                [0] => test
                [1] => Hello
            )

        [asd] => Post
    )

Comment: @AlauddinAnsari can you paste your code in pastbin ?